# Variables de entorno en React: process is not defined

Tags: reactjs, variables

he creado la variable den entorno pero al momento de llamarla en el componente de react para mostrarla por consola me dice process is not defined [image: este es el codigo, la variable esta afuera de la carpeta frontend]

Answer (score 0):

Parece que falta instalar un paquete de `npm`, aquí una lista de revisión:

- El archivo `.env` debe estar en el `root directory`,
- Instalar el package `dotenv` para asegurar `enviroment variables`:

> npm install dotenv

- Importar `dotenv` en el archivo donde se va usar la variable (para este caso Users.jsx)

> import * as dotenv from 'dotenv'